# SAS - proc import/export Physical file does not exist

Tags: sas

I try to import/export files from SAS, without using the export wizard.

To my understanding, my company runs SAS on a **unix** server, whereas i want to a windows drive. We use the SAS EG in a Citrix environment.

According to our IT guys, there is a UNIX directory mapped to a windows drive (or vice versa?) and I should be able to access the following directory in SAS:

```
/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/
```

This is what I got so far:

```
proc export
    data=work.exp1
    outfile="/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv" dbms=csv;
run;
```

This produces an error:

```
ERROR: Physical file does not exist, /sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.EXP1.

0 records created in /sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv from WORK.EXP1.
```

However, further down the log tells me that the file was successfully created

```
NOTE: "/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv" file was successfully created.
```

...when clearly it is not there (I can neither see nor reimport it).

What did I miss? Are there any obvious mistakes in my code?

Comment: It seems strange that you would have that note about the file being successfully created when running that `proc export` if indeed that proc is all you are running. Aside from that, could it be that the path is wrong? In UNIX, a slash `/` at the start of a path indicates the system root and the path is therefore a full path. Relative paths start with a period, two periods or a folder name. Do you know if x commands are allowed in your environement? If you don't, you could find out by running for instance `x 'echo test';` which should run smoothly if it is.

Comment: thanks for this giving that helpful explanation! The 2nd note `NOTE: "/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv" file was successfully created.` will remain a mystery ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should before exporting check if the folder is existing.

With the following functions :

```
/**
*
* @dev Function to check if a file/folder is existing
* @param dsn The pathname of the file/folder to be checked
*
*/

%macro checkFile(dsn /*Enter a pathname Ex: C:\myfile.txt */);
    %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&dsn)) %then
        %do;
            %put &dsn. exists.;
            data _null_;call symputx("checkFile",1,'G');run;
        %end;
    %else
        %do;
            %put &dsn. not exists.;
            data _null_;call symputx("checkFile",0,'G');run;
        %end;
%mend checkFile;

%checkFile("/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/");
%put checkFile=&checkFile;
```

your export

```
%checkFile("/sas_p/gridshared/sh/eg_data/b036081/exp1_test.csv");
%put checkFile=&checkFile;
```

It will give you the information about the folder in the log.
After retry the proc export. Because if the folder is existing, there is no reasons to fail.

and redo a checkFile if the output is created or not.
Don't worry to much about the warning message, SAS sometimes give you wrong information. In fact, your file is not created but SAS does give you a message saying it's okay.

If the file is not created, contact the adminstrator, it's surely a problem of access. Because you did use as expected the proc export, respecting the duble quote and / for linux environement system.

Regards,

Comment: This is amazingly helpful, whish I had this years ago at my old job! Turns out: there was a typo in the address the IT supplied, which I finally identified after checking the `SASUSER` and `WORK` libraries paths.